# When running a TFS build, will it always download all the files for the project?

Tags: tfs, build-process

When running a TFS build, will it always download all the files for the project, or can it use a previous builds download (as long as the files didn't change).

Answer (score 2):

TFS build (2008) will always get all sources specified in build configuration, recreate workspace and force get of sources before doing a build.

If you add

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to your [Build name].proj configuration file then it will do only incremental build and get only changed files. It skips cleaning the files, initializing the workspace and force get steps.

more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833876.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the build in TFS2008 and do "Edit Build Definition..." and then click on the Workspace tab, you can control what is downloaded by the build to limit it to only what you need.  See [this blog post](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs_top_tip_16.html) I wrote on the topic.

Additionally, you can enable incremental gets in TFS if you would like by setting the following property in your TFSBuild.proj file.

```
<IncrementalGet>true</IncrementalGet>
```

That will then only download the files required each time.

Answer (score -1):

TFS keeps records of which versions of the files you have, so when you do a 'get' it only will bring over the files that have changed since your last 'get'.  It's possible to override this behavior with the "/force" option, but it's rarely needed.

Answer (score -3):

It should only ever download if you do a "Get Latest".

Every other build will do it locally.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Why would TFS download all the files for the project everytime you build? It doesn't. If you do a "Get Latest" on the project, and force it, then it will get the files. The build will always be local.